# Dependency Injection Issue of Two MVC Projects in the Same solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, dependency-injection, ninject

I had a web solution with a single MVC project. I have used Ninject binding in this project for constructor injection and it worked fine. Now I added another MVC project to the same solution and used construction injection in this new project too. The new project became the start Up project. But when the project is run, it will give an error called "No parameterless constructor defined for this object.". If I add a parameterless constructor in the corresponding controller, this error will go away. But constructor binding will not occur as the parameterless constructor is called at this time. I even tried to create a separate library for dependency resolving and use that DLL in the MVC project. But this will create a circular dependency, hence it wasn't successful.
What should be the solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this in the past by calling `MapperConfig.RegisterMaps();` in `Global.asax.cs` and defining the `RegisterMaps()` method as the following:

```
public class MapperConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterMaps()
    {
      //get all projects' AutoMapper profiles using reflection
      var assembliesToScan = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
      var allTypes = assembliesToScan.SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes).ToArray();

      //depending on your solution, you may need allTypes to be defined as:
      //var allTypes = assembliesToScan.Where(x => !x.IsDynamic).SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes).ToArray();

      var profiles =
          allTypes
              .Where(t => typeof(Profile).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo()))
              .Where(t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);

      //add each profile to our static AutoMapper
      Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
      {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
          cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

then in each project in the solution, you can have separate automapper profiles (which I like so that your automapper bindings are defined in the layer that uses them instead of throwing all mappings into 1 enormous file) like this:

```
  public class AutoMapperServicesConfig : Profile
  {
    public AutoMapperServicesConfig()
    {
      CreateMap<Entity, EntityViewModel>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
      get { return this.GetType().ToString(); }
    }
  }
```